# adding "ness" always make an adjective to a noun

Tags: nouns, suffixes, word-formation

Is it always possible to add **ness** at the end of adjective to make them noun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not always true; for example, **next**. Some adjectives have their own nouns, like **indifferent**.